# Choose installation folder during setup Visual Studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, installation

I created a Setup Project with Visual Studio Installer.

I would that the user can change the installation path during setup with a specific one, such us "Please select the 'Manager' path location of Inforyou" here Inforyou is an other software installed in the computer.

Is it possible?

Thanks,
Luca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no support in Visual Studio for customizing the install folder dialog. You'd need to do it after the MSI is built with a tool such as Orca. For example, if you open the MSI file with Orca and search for -the installer will install- then you can edit that text to be what you want, then save the MSI file.